# Not able to install rails version 3.2.x in linux mint 14.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using Rails 2.3.14 problem is i want to update rails version to 3.2.x

**1. sudo gem update rails**

-Updating installed gems
-Nothing to update

**2.when i used sudo apt-get update rails**

-The update command takes no arguments

**3.when i tried to install Rails sudo gem install rails --version=3.2.3**

-Fetching: activesupport-3.2.3.gem (100%)
Fetching: builder-3.0.4.gem (100%)
Fetching: activemodel-3.2.3.gem (100%)
Fetching: rack-1.4.4.gem (100%)
Fetching: sprockets-2.1.3.gem (100%)
Fetching: actionpack-3.2.3.gem (100%)
Fetching: activerecord-3.2.3.gem (100%)
Fetching: activeresource-3.2.3.gem (100%)
Fetching: mail-2.4.4.gem (100%)
Fetching: actionmailer-3.2.3.gem (100%)
Fetching: thor-0.14.6.gem (100%)
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

```
    /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 extconf.rb
```

/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- mkmf (LoadError)
    from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in`require'
    from extconf.rb:1:in `'

Gem files will remain installed in /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.7.6 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.7.6/ext/json/ext/generator/gem_make.out

Can anybody suggest me how can i overcome this issue.

Answer (score 0):

first install

```
sudo aptitude install ruby1.9.1-dev
```

will solve your problem

Comment: Thanks for your replay.I have already install ruby,ruby gem and rails.Version